# Automatic mediawiki import with powershell_script

Tags: powershell, permissions, import, mediawiki

I found a nice script to import xml using powershell

http://slash4.de/tutorials/Automatic_mediawiki_page_import_powershell_script

Currently I don't get them run. I'm sure, this is a problem with the permissons.

First I set the wiki to allow anybody to upload an import

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['import']       = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['importupload'] = true;
```

Then I get this error: `Import failed: Loss of session data`.

I try to figure out to pass the user and password to this line in powershell

```
$req.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

and changed it to

```
$req.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::("user", "pass")
```

`Import failed: Loss of session data.` Again?

How can I pass the user/password to the website?

Comment: What is the code you're trying to run?

Comment: i run the original code from the website. I just played around with the line _$req.Credentials_. I tried this one _$req.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::("user", "pass")_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Loss of session data` error is generated when the [edit token](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aEdit_token) sent with the request does not have the expected value.

In the script you linked to, the `$wikiURL` string contains `editToken=12345`.  That does *not* look like a valid MediaWiki edit token, so it's not surprising that it will fail.

In current versions of MediaWiki, the edit token for non-logged-in users is always `+\`.  You could try replacing `12345` in the script with that (or, rather, with its URL-encoded version `%2B%5C`) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem.

Comment: @ozz Remeber to accept this as the answer selecting the v sign on the left!